# How can I exclude folders in All-in-One WP Migration?（outside of the theme file)

Tags: wordpress, backup

I want to exclude the folder wp-content/themes/directory-name/src/node_modules from backup. For this I used the following hook in the functions.php of my theme:

wp-content/themes/directory-name/theme-name/functions.php

```
add_filter(
    'ai1wm_exclude_themes_from_export',
    function ( $exclude_filters ) {
        $exclude_filters = array(
            '../directory-name/src',
        );
        return $exclude_filters;
    }
);
```

```
add_filter(
    'ai1wm_exclude_themes_from_export',
    function ( $exclude_filters ) {
        $exclude_filters = array(
            '/wp-content/themes/directory-name/src',
        );
        return $exclude_filters;
    }
);
```